# SAS Array change to header ext

Tags: sas

I have a large data set with 73 columns of characteristics. If a member has a 1 in the box then they have the characteristic. I would like to change all of the 1s to the characteristic name. When uploading the data set I changed all columns to text and can use the following code to replace the 1s with "Yes" but trying to figure out how to change them to the column header text. ie "Single", "Married" etc..

```
 DATA DataSetb; 
        SET DataSetA ;
        array change _CHARACTER_  ;
        do over change;
        if change=1. then change=????????
        End;
        run;
```

Comment: You should provide some code. What have you tried since now? Which is your approach?

Comment: Do you know how to use a format?

Comment: @DaFois There's actually code there, though not properly formatted.

Comment: In SAS reporting and there are two implicit column header texts. One is the column name and the other is the column label.  Can you explain the reasoning for this value transformation ? Knowning the end goal we might be able to show you that the change is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if the variables are character in the first place and if they are you also need to make sure the length will hold the name. 
Assuming these are accounted for you can use the `VNAME()` function to retrieve the name.

`DO OVER` is deprecated (20 years ago) so I don't use it. This will work, if the assumptions above are met.

You may also want to declare another array with the names if the length isn't large enough.

```
do i=1 to dim(change);
    if change(i)='1' then change=vname(change(i));
End;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `VNAME()` function. Note you need to have defined the variables long enough to hold the names.  SAS variable names can be up to 32 characters long.

Here is example code you can try that will show what happens if the variables are too short.  Notice how the value of SEX is truncated to just 'S' since that variable is defined with length=$1.

```
data test;
  set sashelp.class ;
  array _c _character_;
  do over _c ; _c=vname(_c); end;
run;

proc freq ; 
  tables _character_ / list ;
run;
```

[image]